# Invalid CORS request using when using kickstart libraries

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

When using the kickstart graphql libraries I am recieving

```
Invalid CORS request
```

as the response for the query requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `graphql.kickstart.autoconfigure.web.servlet.GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration` auto enabled CORS:

```
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnClass({CorsFilter.class})
  @ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = {"graphql.servlet.corsEnabled"},
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = true
  )
  public CorsFilter corsConfigurer(CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration) {
```

Setting `graphql.servlet.corsEnabled` to false in your `application.properties` solves the issue.